# good practice to not have user access other user's information when fetching to SQL in PHP from AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax, security

I'm currently fetching user's information that way :

```
require_once '../dbCred.php';

$id = $_GET["id"];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password, $db_opt);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

echo json_encode($stmt->fetch());
```

I'm calling this page named getUtilisateur.php in AJAX.

But if I alter GET data, I can easily retrieve every user's informations.

What is a good way to prevent users from accessing this information ?

I was thinking of a "key" stored with the user and having access to user's information that way.

EDIT : theres' no login in my app
EDIT2 : my application is a survey, when the first user is done answering the survey, he send it to another user, then I compare both survey. So the second user get an URL like survey.html?user_id=1, what I want is something like survey.html?key=dqqsd454qsq988. Is that possible ? Would it be secure enough ?

Comment: Umm, sessions come to mind....

Comment: I was thinking about it too, but that would only secure CSRF-style hack in my mind. Or there's something I don't understand

Comment: Yep. Login and authentication sets a SESSION user ID. From there, you perform user-specific queries from that ID in session. Or if you wanted to superuser to run queries for other user IDs, you would validate beforehand.

Comment: I edited my question, there's not login in my application.

Comment: So how does your application currently know which user is trying to get this information?

Comment: You're basically asking "how do I authenticate and authorize users in my application".  That's a very broad question.  There are many PHP tutorials available for building some kind of authentication system.  Ultimately, when your question is "How do I prevent User A from seeing User B's data?" then the first thing you need to ask yourself is "How do I *know who User A is*?"

Comment: I should have said that it's a survey, when a user is done filling it, he send it to another user who need to also fill it. So currently I have something like survey.html?user_id=1

Comment: To answer your question it is essential to know what is certainly wrong with "retrieving every user's information."

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is effectively impossible. What's stopping me from masquerading as you and accessing "your" data. If there is no login then there is no such thing as "your" data

Comment: @Hayanno What if users2 sends it back to user1? Does user1 become user3?

Comment: What i want is a "key" so that people cannot just type random id and get user's informations. If, instead of survey.html?user_id=1 I could have survey.html?key=51461dsqd4615dsqd5, wouldn't is be secure enough ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus when the second user is done with the survey, it become archived and cannot be modified

Comment: `survey.html?key=51461dsqd4615dsqd5` should work just fine as long as it is always a unique and random code. It's technically guess-able but no one is going to waste their time trying to break your survey app if you use a random code like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have authentication, there is no way for the server to know whether the person doing the query is allowed to do it or not.

If you need such security measure, which seems to be your case, you need to implement a secure authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

Good day sir. The good thing you can do is enable a login page using email/username and password then fetch the user information via email and password only. for password use hash and salt it so that it will be secured. Use google recaptcha also to prevent from robot to or script to be filtered and always sanitize all inputs to be saved to database using some php sanitation code.